# Using LINQ or equivalent to format the console output of List objects

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist

Not sure how this can be done, guessing C# LINQ maybe possible.
So I have an object:

```
public class NContainer {
   public string _HostFqdn { get; set; }
   public string _HostIp { get; set; }
   public int _Severity { get; set; }
   public string _Issue { get; set; }
   public string _ProtoPort { get; set; } }
```

I give it a list like the following:

```
List<NContainer> nList = new List<NContainer>();
nList.Add( new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab1.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.2", _Severity = 1, _Issue = "Check 1", _ProtoPort = "TCP_80" } );
nList.Add( new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab2.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.3", _Severity = 2, _Issue = "Check 2", _ProtoPort = "TCP_81" } );
nList.Add( new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab3.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.4", _Severity = 1, _Issue = "Check 2", _ProtoPort = "TCP_82" } );
nList.Add( new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab4.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.5", _Severity = 3, _Issue = "Check 1", _ProtoPort = "TCP_80" } );
nList.Add( new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab5.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.6", _Severity = 3, _Issue = "Check 5", _ProtoPort = "TCP_443" } );
nList.Add( new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab6.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.7", _Severity = 4, _Issue = "Check 1", _ProtoPort = "TCP_80" } );
```

I want to be able to run LINQ query (or similar query)on the above list so that the console output would be in the format of:

```
Group By _Issue
   Check 1 
   192.168.0.2 TCP_80   192.168.0.5 TCP_82   192.168.0.7 TCP_80

   Check 2
   192.168.0.3 TCP_81   192.168.0.4 TCP_82   

   Check 5
   192.168.0.6 TCP_443
```

I can display the contents of the List and orderby using code similar to below, but cant work out how to display the output in the format above?

```
List<NContainer> arrList = new List<NContainer>();
List<NContainer> query = from NContainer vulns in arrList
                                orderby vulns._Issue
                                where vulns._Severity >= 1
                                select vulns;

    foreach (var vuln in query)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", vuln._Issue, vuln._HostIp, vuln._ProtoPort);
    }
```

Comment: It may be worthwhile updating your question to show what your current code **does** output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by _Issue and write to console as follows

```
var results = nList.GroupBy(x=>x._Issue);

Console.WriteLine("Group By _Issue");
foreach(var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    var IpString = string.Join("  ",item.ToList().Select(x=> $"{x._HostIp} {x._ProtoPort}"));
    Console.WriteLine(IpString);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output

```
Group By _Issue
Check 1
192.168.0.2 TCP_80  192.168.0.5 TCP_80  192.168.0.7 TCP_80

Check 2
192.168.0.3 TCP_81  192.168.0.4 TCP_82

Check 5
192.168.0.6 TCP_443
```

Comment: Thanks Anu, that worked as well, more condensed neater way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be fancier ways to do it, but this works:

```
        List<NContainer> nList = new List<NContainer>();
        nList.Add(new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab1.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.2", _Severity = 1, _Issue = "Check 1", _ProtoPort = "TCP_80" });
        nList.Add(new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab2.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.3", _Severity = 2, _Issue = "Check 2", _ProtoPort = "TCP_81" });
        nList.Add(new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab3.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.4", _Severity = 1, _Issue = "Check 2", _ProtoPort = "TCP_82" });
        nList.Add(new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab4.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.5", _Severity = 3, _Issue = "Check 1", _ProtoPort = "TCP_80" });
        nList.Add(new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab5.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.6", _Severity = 3, _Issue = "Check 5", _ProtoPort = "TCP_443" });
        nList.Add(new NContainer { _HostFqdn = "ab6.corp.com", _HostIp = "192.168.0.7", _Severity = 4, _Issue = "Check 1", _ProtoPort = "TCP_80" });

        IEnumerable<NContainer> query = from NContainer vulns in nList
                                 orderby vulns._Issue
                                 where vulns._Severity >= 1
                                 select vulns;

        Console.WriteLine("Group by _Issue");
        var prevIssue = "";
        bool first = true;
        foreach (var vuln in query)
        {
            if (prevIssue != vuln._Issue)
            {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", vuln._Issue);
                Console.Write("\t");
                prevIssue = vuln._Issue;
            }
            Console.Write("{0} {1}  ", vuln._HostIp, vuln._ProtoPort);
        }
```

Basically use Console.Write instead of WriteLine so that you can loop through and append all of the IP info for a specific info to the same line. The rest is just formatting really.